# Python - create mask of unique values in array

Tags: python, performance, optimization, numpy, mask

I have two numpy arrays, `x` and `y` (the length are around 2M). The `x` are ordered, but some of the values are identical.

The task is to remove values for both `x` and `y` when the values in `x` are identical. My idea is to create a mask. Here is what I have done so far:

```
def createMask(x):
  idx = np.empty(x.shape, dtype=bool)
  for i in xrange(len(x)-1):
    if x[i+1] == x[i]:
      idx[i] = False

  return idx

idx = createMask(x)
x   = x[idx]
y   = y[idx]
```

This method works fine, but it is slow (705ms with `%timeit`). Also I think this look really clumpsy. Is there are more elegant and efficient way (I'm sure there is).

**Updated with best answer**

The **second** method is

```
idx = [x[i+1] == x[i] for i in xrange(len(x)-1)]
```

And the **third** (and fastest) method is

```
idx = x[:-1] == x[1:]
```

The results are (using ipython's `%timeit`):

**First** method: 751ms

**Second** method: 618ms

**Third** method: 3.63ms

Credit to mtitan8 for both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the fastest method is to compare `x` using numpy's `==` array operator:

```
idx = x[:-1] == x[1:]
```

On my machine, using `x` with a million random integers in [0, 100],

```
In[15]: timeit idx = x[:-1] == x[1:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
```

Comment: There is indeed some speedup. Went from 708ms to 559ms. Thank you. I'm still looking for more speedup.

Comment: I think this is more than sufficient. Thank you. I have implemented both methods in my original question with perfomance.